# How to pass paramater from parent component to child component inside condition case in React js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, jsx

I am trying to pass state from parent component to child component and inside Link tag which change route, but in child component I get and undefined value. Is there way to send param and also change route simultaneously?

```
class Teacher extends Component {

   constructor(props) {
    super(props)

    this.state = {
      showComponent: false,
      allStudents: ["a","b", "c", "d"],
    }
  }
  onButtonClick() {
    this.setState({showComponent: true});}

render() {
    console.log(this.state.allStudents+" student list")
    return (

     <Link to={"/student"}>
            <Button onClick={()=> {this.onButtonClick()}}>Button</Button>
           

        {this.state.showComponent &&
           <CreateExam test={this.state.allStudents} /> 
        } 
     </Link>

 </div>
)}
```

Child Component

```
class CreateExam extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }
  render() {
    console.log(this.props.allStudents + " student list") 

    return (
      <div className="teacher">
      </div>

    );
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Inside your **onButtonClick** function, you're replacing your state with `{showComponent: true}`. Therefore, `allStudents` gets lost.

Instead the function should be:

```js
onButtonClick() {
    this.setState(prevState => ({...prevState, showComponent: true}));
}
```

Also use same prop name as what you send from parent.

```js
<CreateExam test={this.state.allStudents} /> 

console.log(this.props.test + " student list")
```

Refer: https://jsfiddle.net/t9j7hmdb/